# whats the best way to format Django Templates in VSCODE?

Tags: django, django-templates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDBWt.png)

VSCode prettier formatter makes this template format in weird way and i get error in django.

I have tried multiple Django Extensions , Prettier ,etc.
can anyone share best vscode extensions and settings for django .

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem using these :

1.Install this Extension : [Extension Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDOBM.png)

2.1.Edit Settings JSON file like this

```
"[django-html]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "junstyle.vscode-django-support"
},
```